# How do I dump linker library search paths from the linux linker. Using 'make'

Tags: linux, linker-errors

How do I get my 'make' process to show me the actual search paths and libraries found with the linker?

I have link errors for symbols I know are in libraries I am trying to use ( verified using objdump ). What I don't know is if the linker is finding the correct libraries.  It should be, since all of the libraries I am using are in one directory and some of them ARE being found and used.

So I would like to get diagnostic output showing what library search paths were used, and what libraries ( with paths ) that were actually found and used by the linker.

I tried make -n and got

g++ -g   -Wall  -DLINUX  -I../../../Common/include -I../../../Common/libs/liblua/src  main.o  IDUpdater.o  version.o -L../../../Common/libs -lapp -lserver -lthreading -lnet -lmsgqueue -lcpp -lisam -lisamcore -ldb -ldbisam -ldbsql -Wl,--whole-archive  -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o foo

I know libisam.a ,libdbisam.a and others are found and used, but libmsgqueue.a is not.  These libraries are all in ../../..'Common/libs/.

Comment: It may help if you post the error output of the linker.

Comment: just the standard undefined reference.

Comment: ../../../Common/libs/libmsgqueue.a(MsgQueue.o)(.text+0x8bc): In function `MsgQueue::ConnectWriter(String&, String&, MsgQueueTypes)':
/home/kclark/tfs/Linux3/Common/libs/libmsgqueue/MsgQueue.cpp:68: undefined reference to `MessageQ::Create(int)'

Comment: In which library is `MessageQ::Create(int)` defined? Is the order of the libraries correct?